# How to select rows with NaN in multiple columns without knowing which ones?

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have a dataframe:

```
    0   1   2   3   4   5
0   1A  2   3   4   nan 6
1   1   2   3   nan 5   nan
2   1A  2   nan nan nan nan
3   1   2   nan nan nan nan
4   1   2   3   4   5   6
```

I want to delete rows with a condition in df[0] and where columns 2: are nan.
I can't get the 2nd part.

I try to select the rows to drop using:

```
df.loc[:,2:].isnull()
```

but that selects rows with any nulls in the last columns, I want the rows where all the columns from 2: are null

I don't want to name the columns because the dataframe won't always have the same number of columns.
The only solution I'm thinking of now would be to determine the number of columns in the dataframe, then use

```
df.loc[x,2].isnull() & df.loc[x,3].isnull() ...
```

which seems clunky.
Ideally I want a way to check if there are nulls in all columns after column 2 (df.loc[x,2:])

Comment: `df.loc[:,2:].isnull().all(1)`.

Comment: What would your expected output look like? A boolean with True if all columns after column two have at least one null value?

Comment: What @QuangHoang posted is exactly what I wanted. So yes a boolean with True/False that I can use.

Comment: @QuangHoang How would I get the dataframe for that subset? When I try ```df[df.loc[:,2:].isnull().all(1)]``` I get an error ```IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match```

Answer (score 3):

[Quang Hong](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4238408/quang-hoang) gave me an answer in a comment that is what I was looking for:

```
df.loc[:,2:].isnull().all(1)
```